# groovy error on command line and groovyConsole

Tags: java, groovy

When I try to run the following code I get an error:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
groovy:000> 1st = [1, 2, 3]
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

This is the error that I get:

```
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[1, 2, 3]]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), abs(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), and(java.lang.Number)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
```

Any ideas what the problem may be??

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables can't begin with a digit.  Changing 1st to first is enough to make everything work as expected:

```
 first = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: weird... the tutorial in the book shows using 1st as a variable!!  I took your suggestion and all is well!!  Thanks!!

Comment: @ ironmantis7x : which book/ which tutorial? Please notify the author!

Comment: @Jeffrey: it was a refcardz cheat sheet